# How to plot on box plot 2 data from different data frama - Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, dataframe, boxplot

I'm facing a problem to plot 2 box plots into a same graph to make easier to compare them.
The problems is that each box plot comes from a different dataframe with different lenght, however, both have same columns.

My two data frame are:
'headlamp_water' and 'headlamp_crack'; the column I want to use is called 'Use Period'.
[image]
How do I do it?
Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: it's easier to help you if you post small samples of your data frames.

Comment: @JulienSpronck I attached a picture with the data frame, both dataframes are similar (same columns, the only different I have only filtered the mode of faliure and created the 2 dataframes I mentioned above)

Comment: @RafaelRodriguesSantos please understand that, due to the interactive nature of dataframe she, people want to play with data to answer your question and they are not going to help easily if they have picture material instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [concat()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) the columns and call the [boxplot()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) method.

```
pd.concat([headlamp_water['Use Period'], headlamp_crack['Use Period']], axis=1).boxplot()
```

Using `axis=1`, you select the columns.

Comment: It has worked perfectly, thank you very much @Jose Raul Barreras